# DB Schema Design

Tags: mongodb

Currently working on trying to model a DB schema in MongoDB. The bit I'm getting stuck on is where an employee must indicate their times that they are available to work.

I.e.

Monday:
   9AM-12PM, 2:00PM-6:00PM

Tuesday: 
   8AM-10AM, 12:00PM-2:00PM, 4:00PM-6:00PM

etc.

I could just have an embedded field in my schema with a list of times, but I'm not sure if thats the best solution to this.

Opinions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal rule when it comes to schema design. I would store a list of numerical ranges, where a range's unit is seconds from the beginning of workweek. This way it would be possible to use mongo to search directly for available personnel in a single query. Date manipulation should not be a problem on a modern platform.